# C# Издатель-Подписчик через RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Решил разобраться с меж сервисным взаимодействием через брокер сервис очереди RabbitMQ.
И подвернулась задача где его можно использовать для обмена данными между программами.

Есть 4 физических компьютера в сети:

1 - Издатель. раз в секунду отправляет состояние модели.

2 - Брокер сервер с установленным и запущенным сервисом RabbitMq

3 - Подписчик 1. Получает состояния модели.

4 - Подписчик 2. Получает состояния модели.

Для быстрого тестирования создал 2 проекта WinForms.

Server.Publisher

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ConnectionFactory ConnectionFactory { get; set; }
    public IConnection Connect { get; set; }
    public IModel Channel { get; set; }
    public bool IsConnectToBus { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubscriberNotified { get; set; }// Подписчики оповещены

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var hostName = @"192.168.1.40";
            ConnectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = hostName,
                Port = 5672,
                UserName = "user",
                Password = "password",
                VirtualHost = "/",
                AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
                TopologyRecoveryEnabled = true,
                NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
            };

            //Подключение
            Connect = ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection();

            //Создание канала обмена
            Channel = Connect.CreateModel();
            Channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "dataExchange", type: "direct");

            IsConnectToBus = Connect.IsOpen;
            tb_isConnect.Text = IsConnectToBus.ToString();
        }
        catch (RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Соединение прерванно {ex.ToString()}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }

    private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var message = tb_message.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mrssage = NULL");
            return;
        }

        var routingKey = tb_route.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(routingKey))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("routingKey = NULL");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            Channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "dataExchange", routingKey: routingKey, basicProperties: null, body: body);
        }
        catch (RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Соединение прерванно {ex.ToString()}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }



    private void btn_DisConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Channel?.Close(200, "Goodbye");
        Connect?.Close();
    }


    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        Channel?.Close(200, "Goodbye");
        Connect?.Close();
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
```

Client.Consumer

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ConnectionFactory ConnectionFactory { get; set; }
    public IConnection Connect { get; set; }
    public IModel Channel { get; set; }
    public bool IsConnectToBus { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubscriberNotified { get; set; }// Подписчики оповещенны

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var hostName = @"192.168.1.40";
            ConnectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = hostName,
                Port = 5672,
                UserName = "user",
                Password = "password",
                VirtualHost = "/",
                AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
                TopologyRecoveryEnabled = true,
                NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
            };

            //Подключение
            Connect = ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection();

            //Создание канала обмена
            Channel = Connect.CreateModel();
            Channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "dataExchange", type: "direct");
            var queueName = Channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
            Channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName, exchange: "dataExchange", routingKey: tb_route.Text);

            //Подписка на событие получения данных
            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(Channel);
            consumer.Received += Consumer_Received;  
            Channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);

            IsConnectToBus = Connect.IsOpen;
            tb_isConnect.Text = IsConnectToBus.ToString();
        }
        catch (RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Соединение прерванно {ex.ToString()}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }

    private void Consumer_Received(object model, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea)
    {
        var body = ea.Body;
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        var routingKey = ea.RoutingKey;
        tb_ReciveData.Text = message;
    }

    private void btn_DisConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Channel?.Close(200, "Goodbye");
        Connect?.Close();
    }


    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        Channel?.Close(200, "Goodbye");
        Connect?.Close();
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
```

ВОПРОСЫ:

1.Как издатель поймет что его подписчики уведомлены?

2. Как издатель и подписчик отреагируют на выключение из сети Брокер сервиса RabbitMQ?
   Т.е. мне нужно просто выставить состояние "IsConnect = false".
   Сработает какое-то событие или я пойму только по Exception при отправке от издателя?
   Как тогда понять подписчику что созданная очередь для этого обмена больше не доступна?
3. Будет ли RabbitMQ пытаться восстанавливать соединение в случае выключения из сети Брокер сервиса RabbitMQ если выставлено AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
               TopologyRecoveryEnabled = true?

   Как я пойму что соединение восстановлено "IsConnect = true"?

Comment: а что об этом пишет документация к RabbitMQ?

Comment: К сожалению именно на эти вопросы я ответы не нашел. Вопросы про восстановление соединения можно просто проверить что будет, пока этим не занимался. А вот первый вопрос не понятно. Неужели нужно также публиковать сообщение в обработчике события получения данных в другую очередь. Одна очередь запросы другая ответы.

Comment: Я уже несколько лет не трогал RabbitMQ и тему вообще, но вроде там был где то тип очереди или тип сообщения с информацией источнику о факте доставке сообщения.

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html чем это не устраивает?

Comment: ну или вот целая тема в доках https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Comment: RPC смотрел, но смутило то что это удаленный вызов метода (т.е. какое-то долгое удаленное действие на конкретном подписчике, а не  сразу на всех.). По поводу 2-ой темы почитаю спасибо, сразу не увидел.

Comment: Перепробовал все варианты, но ответ приходит от сервиса RabbitMQ, а не от подписчика. Попробую обертку EasyNetQ для обмена. Если все получится то отвечу на свой вопрос.

Comment: Так оно вроде и должно быть так, разве нет? Что подписчики шлют ответы раббиту, раббит уже уведомляет источник

Comment: Наверно это называется транзакция. когда подписчики уведомляют о получении. у меня она не работает. TxSelect();   Publish(...);  TxCommit(); поидее на TxCommit должна быть блокировка потока выполнения (ожидание ответа), а у меня нету блокровки.

Comment: Кстатит реконеккт работает автоматом отлично и события есть на IsConnect и IsDisconnect